# Custom meta tag configuration

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, meta-tags

I have 2 tables, `page` and `settings`.

`page` is just a bunch of fields, such as name and slug, and has 3 other fields for meta tags (title, keywords, description) and displays a cms page.

The `settings` has 3 fields: default_meta_title, default_meta_keywords, default_meta_description

Now what I'm looking to do is to display the default_meta_* tags in the HTML source if the page I am on does not have the particular meta info set from the cms page.

All pages, except the homepage is managed this way, so I was thinking I'd need to add some code to the `layout.php` to get this to work.

So the homepage will display my default_meta_*, as I cannot set this in the cms `pages` table.

Comment: Can you specify your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem.

First is to use [`sfYaml`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfYaml) class to update `view.yml` with default meta tags (see [documentation about view.yml](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_the_view_yml_file)). After that if specific page should use another metas you can override defaults with [`addMeta` method of response object](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_view_configuration_settings)

Second (as ManseUK suggested) is to declare slot placing code like this into layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <?php include_javascripts() ?>
    <?php include_stylesheets() ?>
    <?php include_title() ?>
    <?php if (has_slot('metas')): ?>
      <?php include_slot('metas') ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php include_component('page', 'metas') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
```

Default metas will be rendered via `page` [components](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_components). On top of your template (i guess  `modules/page/templates/showSuccess.php`) place code

```
<?php slot('metas') ?>
  <?php if($page->hasMetas()):?>
    <!-- code to render nondefault page metas -->
    <?php echo $page->getMetas(); ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php include_component('page', 'metas') ?>
  <?php endif;?>
<?php end_slot() ?>
```

I assume that you will replace `$page->hasMetas()` with real code that will check if your `page` object has metatags.

Actually i would prefer to go further and code `page` components to accept parameters. Code in a template will look like

```
<?php slot('metas') ?>
  <?php include_component('page', 'metas', array('metas'=>$page->getMetas())) ?>
<?php end_slot() ?>
```

Deciding which metas (default or not) should be rendered will take place in `page` components (i assume that you can easily retrieve defaul;t settings from your database). If no parameters were passed (see layout code) than your component should also render default metas.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Brilliant!! Worked like a charm and now renders default meta on all pages that do not have meta defined in the db and also displays the meta from page in db when it is present in the db! Great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slot - check for existence of the slot in the layout - if it exists then add the custom meta fields - if not add the default ones